# Programmatically registering program into Add/Remove programs and storing files within an executable

Tags: c#, installation, uninstallation

I am working on a windows c# console application which I want to allow the user to install on to their computer.

I want to make my own Windows Installer executable as the Setup Deployment tools built into Visual Studio, appear to be somewhat lacking in functionality for customisations and documentation.

Therefore, because I want to make my own Windows installer, how do I register my program into the Add/Remove Programs window so they can choose to uninstall it again if they wish and it relaunches my installer program to do the removal.

Also as well, the executable would obviously need to copy the files into various locations on the PC, i.e. `C:\Program Files` so how would I store the executable files within the windows installer executable so I can move them into the right location.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried the ClickOnce deployment options?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  If you do not like the included windows tool, I'd go right to NSIS:  http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page.

Comment: How about using WiX?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's a routine we use to register our program in Add/Remove Programs:

```
private void CreateUninstaller()
{
    using (RegistryKey parent = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                 @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", true))
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Uninstall registry key not found.");
        }
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = null;

            try
            {
                string guidText = UninstallGuid.ToString("B");
                key = parent.OpenSubKey(guidText, true) ??
                      parent.CreateSubKey(guidText);

                if (key == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Unable to create uninstaller '{0}\\{1}'", UninstallRegKeyPath, guidText));
                }

                Assembly asm = GetType().Assembly;
                Version v = asm.GetName().Version;
                string exe = "\"" + asm.CodeBase.Substring(8).Replace("/", "\\\\") + "\"";

                key.SetValue("DisplayName", "My Program");
                key.SetValue("ApplicationVersion", v.ToString());
                key.SetValue("Publisher", "My Company");
                key.SetValue("DisplayIcon", exe);
                key.SetValue("DisplayVersion", v.ToString(2));
                key.SetValue("URLInfoAbout", "http://www.blinemedical.com");
                key.SetValue("Contact", "support@mycompany.com");
                key.SetValue("InstallDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
                key.SetValue("UninstallString", exe + " /uninstallprompt");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                "An error occurred writing uninstall information to the registry.  The service is fully installed but can only be uninstalled manually through the command line.",
                ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MacGyver, `B` means "32 digits separated by hyphens, enclosed in braces", which is the format the registry uses for guids. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So it looks like "UninstallGuid" and "UninstallRegKeyPath" are undefined in your source code.  I'm assuming the second one is the path of the exe to uninstall the application.  Can you comment on these two please?  I can also post a question to undo this reg key, but that was my third and final question.

Comment: @MacGyver `UninstallRegKeyPath` is the string at the top `@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"`. I hard coded it at the top of the method but didn't notice there was a reference to the variable in the error handling. The guid is just the guid for your installer. You generate a guid for your app and use the same guid every time you install, it's normal part of installation of any Windows app. It only needs to be consistent across versions of your app to uniquely identify your app (unless you support multiple side-by-side versions, then unique for releases within a version).

Comment: @MacGyver, the code creates a registry key. To undo it, delete the registry key.

Comment: Looks like the very bottom of this link contains the source code to remove the key.  https://gist.github.com/erkantaylan/c474781a1e32c730bc51 .... also, if you use = new Guid(), you get all 0's for the GUID.  If you use = Guid.NewGuid(), you get a unique GUID on the machine, but it's all lowercase.  So I'm just working on making it an uppercase to match the rest.

Comment: @MacGyver, you want the guid to be the same across installations, so do not use `Guid.NewGuid()`. Hard code a guid into your code and update it as needed (when you want a new side-by-side install of your app). The `ToString("B")` is what gives you the right guid format.

Comment: @MacGyver, thanks for the link to the Gist. That's actually the full version of my code where the above function came from. I think he probably got it off another Stack Overflow post of mine. Nice to see it shared.

Comment: I imagine it's quite rare to use the same GUID that is already being used in this registry list for Uninstallers.  If we hard code it, I'm just wondering if we will eventually hit a corner case on someone's installation.  I'll try to use an existing GUID in that list and see if it throws an exception.

Comment: @MacGyver, that's not a concern, but if it was, generating a unique guid for each installation would have a much bigger chance of a collision than a single hard-coded guid.

Comment: @MacGyver, while a GUID is not unique, the chances of an eventual hit is so small it "never" occurs. "[---] the probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth as of 2014 owned 600 million GUIDs" [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)

Comment: I ended up building our own installer and it was worth it! With some clean up, I plan on making it open source. Unless you plan on a career that involves installing software (for Windows), I feel it is a waste of time learning Wix, MSI etc. Just my 2c. PS: All modern installers (including the one for VS 2017 uses Wix Burn, so if you want to  a "real" installer, I recommend Wix)

Answer (score 0):

You can try deploying your application using [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or the [Microsoft Installer technology (msi)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310598).

Comment: ClickOnce seems to give you less control than the Visual Studio MSI creation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using MSI Installer in this case as it will allow you to have a control of package details(i.e name), where to copy the files on client and allows adding extra files you want to include as a part of msi installer.

Answer (score 0):

For the love of god do not use clickonce... it is more of a hassle than it is worth. If you do not have administrative rights to a machine and need to install something it is worth the time to ask for permission.

Answer (score -1):

Don't build your own installer, use a proven deployment tool like:
[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) or [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/). All of which are free and has a lot of features.

Comment: don't forget that they have cons on their own like learning curve, yet another programming language, more files to handle, bitness (no AnyCPU), localization

Comment: I don't forget. But give credit to those who build these fairly complex systems that they solved so many issues you will not have the time to do by yourself even if it saves you learning a new language.
As a side note: there is no problem with bitness or localization and you won't end up with more files to handle.

Comment: Add bitrock also. I used it once. It was easy to use. But not open source.

Comment: "don't build your own installer" ,  you got -1

Comment: @Zakos go and build a new one, for each application you are developing. Don't be lazy.

Comment: Building an installer isn't hard. You add your files as resources and register it like Neff says. Then, it's completely in house and branded like your own UI.

Comment: Depends on the nature of your project, but for our application which has many different parts to it, writing our own installer was the best decision we ever made. You have full control over your installation experience, it can make for a much slicker installation process, and in our case the custom written installer was blindingly fast compared with when we used 3rd party tools. YMMV but the time it takes to learn someone else's set of tools could see you well on the way  to writing your own.